# How to multiply two columns and show the result

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my application there is a table that shows the data that I passing from the controller.

Here in the last column I want to show the Total Amount by multiplying the Qty and Unit Amount data.

Can I get a help to do this method? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Requesting Item</th>
        <th>Required Qty</th>
        <th>Unit Amount</th>
        <th>Total Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
        <tbody>
         @{int RowNo = 0;}
         @for (int i = 0; i < Model.First().PurchaseOrderItems.Count; i++)
          {
           <tr>
            <td>@{RowNo++;} @RowNo</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.First().PurchaseOrderItems[i].Item_Description)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.First().PurchaseOrderItems[i].Qty)</td>
            <td>Rs.@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.First().PurchaseOrderItems[i].UnitAmount)</td>
            <td></td>
           </tr>
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle the calculation in your Controller and then set the output of that calculation as a new property on your model (like `TotalAmount` or `PurchasedOrderTotalAmount`. This will make it easier to render in your template.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Requesting Item</th>
        <th>Required Qty</th>
        <th>Unit Amount</th>
        <th>Total Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
        <tbody>
         @{int RowNo = 0;}
         @for (int i = 0; i < Model.First().PurchaseOrderItems.Count; i++)
          {
           <tr>
            <td>@{RowNo++;} @RowNo</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.First().PurchaseOrderItems[i].Item_Description)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.First().PurchaseOrderItems[i].Qty)</td>
            <td>Rs.@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.First().PurchaseOrderItems[i].UnitAmount)</td>
            <td></td>
           </tr>
          }
         <tr>
          <td colspan="4">Total Amount:</td>
          <td>Rs.@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.First().PurchasedOrderTotalAmount)</td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
</div>
```